# Selecting 1 Tool Strip Menu Item at any one time

Tags: vb.net, winforms, toolstripmenu

I have a Tool strip menu with 4 options.
The options are degrees of screen rotation. (0, 90, 180, 270)
I am trying to select only 1 of these and keep it selected.
When I choose one then another, both are ticked (selected).
I have searched and found some solutions but only this works for me.
I have used the click event for each option to clear the ones not chosen like below.

```
Private Sub DegreesToolStripMenuItem6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DegreesToolStripMenuItem6.Click

    DegreesToolStripMenuItem6.Checked = True
    DegreesToolStripMenuItem7.Checked = False
    DegreesToolStripMenuItem8.Checked = False
    DegreesToolStripMenuItem9.Checked = False

End Sub
```

This sub is in my code 4 times to make it work but i'm sure there must be a cleaner, easier way to do this.

I have found online some other solutions but I can't seem to make it work, this one kind of makes sense like it should work but I can't figure it out

```
Private Sub DegreesToolStripMenuItem6_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DegreesToolStripMenuItem6.CheckedChanged, _
    DegreesToolStripMenuItem7.CheckedChanged, _
    DegreesToolStripMenuItem8.CheckedChanged, _
    DegreesToolStripMenuItem9.CheckedChanged

    Dim currentItem As ToolStripMenuItem = TryCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem)

    If currentItem IsNot Nothing AndAlso currentItem.Checked Then
        Dim menu As ContextMenuStrip = TryCast(currentItem.Owner, ContextMenuStrip)

        If menu IsNot Nothing Then
            'The current item has just been checked so uncheck all other items on the same context menu strip.
            For Each item As ToolStripMenuItem In menu.Items
                If item IsNot currentItem Then
                    item.Checked = False
                End If
            Next item
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

the toolstrip menu reads like this

```
-PreferedRotationToolStripMenuItem-DegreesToolStripMenuItem6
                                   DegreesToolStripMenuItem7
                                   DegreesToolStripMenuItem8
                                   DegreesToolStripMenuItem9
```

Thanks for your time and looking forward to any help you guys can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `CheckOnClick` to `True` for each menu item, which I'm guessing you already have. This code worked for me:

```vb
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItems_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DegreesToolStripMenuItem9.CheckedChanged,
                                                                                        DegreesToolStripMenuItem8.CheckedChanged,
                                                                                        DegreesToolStripMenuItem7.CheckedChanged,
                                                                                        DegreesToolStripMenuItem6.CheckedChanged
    Dim currentMenuItem = DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem)

    If currentMenuItem.Checked Then
        Dim menu = DirectCast(currentMenuItem.Owner, ContextMenuStrip)

        For Each menuItem In menu.items.Cast(Of ToolStripMenuItem)
            menuItem.Checked = menuItem Is currentMenuItem
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Here's a slight variation that avoids checking the already checked current item:

```vb
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItems_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DegreesToolStripMenuItem9.CheckedChanged,
                                                                                        DegreesToolStripMenuItem8.CheckedChanged,
                                                                                        DegreesToolStripMenuItem7.CheckedChanged,
                                                                                        DegreesToolStripMenuItem6.CheckedChanged
    Dim currentMenuItem = DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem)

    If currentMenuItem.Checked Then
        Dim menu = DirectCast(currentMenuItem.Owner, ContextMenuStrip)

        For Each menuItem In menu.Items.Cast(Of ToolStripMenuItem).Except({currentMenuItem})
            menuItem.Checked = False
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

The code above works if you have added the items to a `ContextMenuStrip`. If you have added them directly to an item on a `MenuStrip` then change this:

```vb
Dim menu = DirectCast(currentMenuItem.Owner, ContextMenuStrip)
```

to  this:

```vb
Dim menu = DirectCast(currentMenuItem.Owner, ToolStripDropDownMenu)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but both examples are producing an error for me.

Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownMenu' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip'.

Comment: @AlexMcCreath, your original code indicated that you were using a `ContextMenuStrip` rather than a `MenuStrip`. Maybe that's why it didn't work for you. Are your menu items in both or just a `MenuStrip`? I started out using a `MenuStrip` but changed it because of your code.

Comment: this part where this option is a MenuStrip, sorry for the confusion but that's probably why my example didn't work for me.

Comment: @AlexMcCreath, see my edit. It's a simple case of changing the type of the owner. Everything else is the same.

Comment: yes i just noticed this in the error part on the bottom of the screen and it does work with that change so thanks a bunch for your help today